# Cannot activate virtual environment before install django cms

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Curently I'm trying to create a blog locally using django cms. From the tutorial before I install django cms I need to install virtual environment (follow tutorial from [Django-cms-tutorial](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-tutorial/blob/master/Step%201%20-%20Initial%20Setup.md)).

When I trying to install virtual environment using command promt:

```
C:\Python34> virtualenv env
C:\Python34> env\Script\activate
```

The command line showing error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

For information I'm using windows 7.
What should I do to fix this error so I can install virtual environment then install django cms?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to activate virtual envirement on terminal linux you could write one of those:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

or

```
. env/bin/activate
```

to deactivate you may write this command:

```
deactivate
```

in Windows I think you should write the full path such as C:\the-way-to-your-envirement-path\bin\activate like this

```
source C:\the-way-to-your-envirement-path\bin\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

For windows 7 I need to reference the full path, for example:

```
C:\Python34\env\Scripts\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any bin folder and Scripts this is really helpfull: Open your project file on command prompt and write **workon** and this command will show you your environments and write **workon *myvirtualenvname***